# Sequences consisting of letters combined with numbers

Tags: r, sequence

I am trying to form a sequence from a range consisting of letters and numbers. The letters indicate rows and the numbers the columns, together, these form a position. Per row, there are only 9 positions. When these are filled, you move on to the next row, etc.. So the positions can be from A1 - A9, B1 - B9, C1 - C9, D1 - D9, etc etc.

The range could be from A1 - A8, so then the sequence should be A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8
However, the range could also be from A8 - B6. Meaning the sequence would be A8 A9 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6. Would anyone know how this is possible?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a matrix `m` of the possibilities and then look up the `from` and `to` inputs in it creating a sequence.

```
# input
from <- "A8"
to <- "B6"

make_seq <- function(from, to) {
  m <- t(outer(LETTERS, 1:9, paste0))
  m[seq(match(from, m), match(to, m))]
}
make_seq(from, to)
## [1] "A8" "A9" "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it is exactly what I am looking for. Would you happen to know how to apply this in the case that there would be more that one 'from' or 'to' values? So for example: from <- c("A8", "A9", "B1") and to <- c("B6", "B7", "B8") and then that you get three outputs: [1] "A8" "A9" "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6" [2] "A9" "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6" "B7" [3] "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6" "B7" "B8"

Comment: Have modified answer to make it a function. Now we can do this: `Map(make_seq, from, to)` or `mapply(make_seq, from, to)`

Comment: Perfect! This works like a charm. Thanks so much again

Comment: So sorry to bother you again, i just found out that some of the values are NA and then the function does not work. Since mapply does not uses na.omit or na.rm, is there a way to add a statement in the function that returns NA in case either 'from' or 'to' is NA?

Comment: Use an if statement to check whether the arguments are NA:    `if (!is.na(from) && !is.na(to)) { ... } else NA`

Comment: And should I put this in the make_seq function? Or when calling the function? So, if (!is.na(from) && !is.na(to)) {make_seq(from, to)} else NA

Comment: In the function.